# Why does proof of work targeted zeros always comes at the start of hash? why is it not in the middle or the end of hash?

Tags: mining, bitcoin, nonce, proof-of-work, hash-algorithm

My question is why always targeted zeros come at the start of hash of the block? I have never seen more than 2 zeros in middle or somewhere else in the hash of mined block... What's the reason?....

My second question is.... as we know that hash of block is not calculated according to our desired target then why NONCE is always used as a digit? not as alphabetic